# Save data from textbox before page reload ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, save, reload

I've got a little problem saving data from textboxes so that when the page reloads the data does not go into the void.

**Scenario:** on the page load some data gets pulled from SQL table and gets displayed in TextBoxes and a GridView. Now when a client clicks one button some different date gets loaded into the TextBoxes an GridView. Finally the client clicks the second button and some calculations needs to be done with the data that was in the TextBoxes last.

**Problem:** Every time a button gets clicked the page reloads and the data that is in the page_load event gets displayed and used for the calculations instead of the new data that was entered.

I have tried using ajax Update Panel and I have also tried to save the data to the session, but to no avail.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry Furqan... forgot about that. its better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to wrap the logic that does the initial load on the textboxes in

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
}
```

to ensure this only happens once.

Comment: like they say... a little goes a long way!